# Firebase functions throws uncatchable error

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm calling the following Firebase function:

```
exports.getUserRecord = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    try {
        //This successfully logs an existing uid in firestore, it should be retrievable
        console.log(context.auth.uid)

        const doc = admin.firestore().collection('user').doc(context.auth.uid);
        const res = await doc.get() //Isolated it down to this line that is failing
        return res
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unavailable', 'some error message');
    }
});
```

When calling this function I receive the following error on the client:

```
POST https://us-central1-xxx-xxx.cloudfunctions.net/getUserRecord 500
Uncaught (in promise) Error: INTERNAL
```

On the server logs I see this error:

```
Unhandled error function error(...args) {
    write(entryFromArgs('ERROR', args));
}
```

I am wondering how there is an error that neither of my error logging lines are picking up, and also what is causing this error?

EDIT: I have also tried logging other things within my `catch` block but they do not appear, it seems there is an error but the code does not enter the `catch` block somehow.

I have also seen [this post](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/757) which seems to suggest this was an issue that was patched in firebase-functions 3.9.1, but I have upgraded and still have this issue

Comment: A couple of theories to throw out. First,  in `} catch (err) {
        console.log(err)`, if err itself were undefined, you would only get a blank line in your logs, easy to miss.  Second, the only unhandled code in your promise (the async method) is the catch block itself.  What if `throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unavailable', 'some error message');` were throwing an error?   You can test the first by adding message text to your console.log ('am I crazy?' is my favorite).  The second can be tested by commenting out the `throw new...`.  Good luck!

Comment: And yeah I just saw your comment about logging other things in the catch, so probably not that.... sorry

Comment: I walked through the firebase-functions code for onCall at v3.11.0 and I don't see any other issues that could relate to this in the code since the fix. If anything, can you check your current firebase-functions lib installed in node_modules/firebase-functions/package.json file to make sure installed version is higher than fix.

Comment: Hi @EdwardRomero server side it seems I'm using 

`"_from": "firebase-functions@^3.6.1",`
`"_id": "firebase-functions@3.9.0",`

Client side I'm using `@firebase/functions` which seems to be slightly different from the `firebase-functions` I'm using server side. Client side @firebase is version `"^7.15.0",` and @firebase/functions is version `"0.4.45"`

Comment: Hollddd up. I'm just realizing that is not the version I claimed in my post. And my `package.json` in the root directory shows version `3.6.1` even though I ran `npm i firebase-functions` and it said `+ firebase-functions@3.11.0
updated 1 package and audited 476 packages in 2.395s`

Comment: So this must be the issue but why is my package not being updated when it says it should be. Is `npm i firebase-functions` not the right command to update it

Comment: @Matt when i upgrade i do one of two things. `npm i firebase-functions@latest --save` or   `npm i firebase-functions@<exact version i want> --save`, I've seen some times just running `npm i <package>` doesn't update the `package.json` or `package-lock.json`. Also I usually delete my node_modules after i do all my updates to make sure my setup is clean the same way that it would be running in a pipeline or deployed

Comment: Also when looking at the version within node_modules, I look at attribute "version": "3.11.0" within the package.json file rather than _from or _id.

Comment: This worked! Thank you - I was using the wrong version of `firebase-functions` and had used the wrong command to update it. I'm now seeing the above function is somehow giving me a `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error (which is progress because I could not see this before)

Comment: @Matt call `res.data()` to avoid returning the firebase complex objects from get -- https://github.com/firebase/snippets-node/blob/48ca0c7e7dabe2777b40cbd1d8efb5194711c217/firestore/main/index.js#L491-L497. Also, thank you for the bounty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Walked through the firebase-functions code for onCall at v3.11.0 and I don't see any other issues that could relate to this in the code since the fix

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/757

After discussing with @Matt about node_module versions we found that the issue is related to node_modules not having updated to latest once the upgrade was initially done.

**Notes for anyone running into this issue in the future**

If updating to latest for this module make sure to do the following to cover all bases,

Look into `node_modules/firebase-functions/package.json` attribute `version` to make sure that the proper version is installed.

Also take a look at your root folder package.json and package-lock.json to makes sure the proper versions are the latest.

If anything is not at version v3.9.1 or higher, then do the following,

```
    rm -rf node_modules
    npm i firebase-functions@latest --save
```

After that, double check everything again to make sure all is good.